# How to handle snapshot.data with hasData, hasError, and ConnectionState in Flutter StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm not sure about how to handle Flutter StreamBuilder. I found 3 cases and want to know which one would be better than others with any reason. Or if there is a better way to handle it other than these cases.

Also, what is the difference between **ConnectionState.active** and **ConnectionState.done**? Should I wait using **snapshot.data** until **ConnectionState.done** or not (**Case 1** Or **Case 2**).

**Case 1:**

```
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            return Text('${snapshot.data}');
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
```

**Case 2:**

```
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          case ConnectionState.done:
            return Text('${snapshot.data}');
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
```

**Case 3:**

```
    return StreamBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error');
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return Text('${snapshot.data}');
      },
    );
```

Comment: if connection state none to improve user experience, show a message. If connection state done, check if snapshot.hasData and display widget or if error show again a message. Active and waithing can be used to show indicator or anything you like. Active means(basic) connection is alive.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I thought checking snapshot.hasData and ConnectionState were the same things just matter of granularity, so I don't know If ConnectionState.done, I still need to check snapshot.hasData. The other thing is only when  ConnectionState.done, I should access to snapshot.data, 
 or I can also use snapshot.data with Widget when ConnectionState.active too?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html) it states the the difference between active and done is that **`ConnectionState.active`** : is the Stream that its not done yet but returned at least one value,
**`ConnectionState.done`** : where it has terminated the asynchronous computation/transaction you are dealing with.

---

regarding your question on when should you wait, It depends on the kind of computation you are doing.

Normally `ConnectionState.active` is more important to take care of because you are dealing with a stream which means data could be updated and the state of your app should also update.

You can use `ConnectionState.done` to make sure you fetched the data and the asynchronous connection is terminated.

To get a good idea on how to deal with `StreamBuilder` and `QuerySnapshot` check out [Firebase for Flutter](https://codelabs.flutter-io.cn/codelabs/flutter-firebase/index.html#10)